# Change output directory in "sbt-native-packager"

Tags: directory, sbt, mapping, packaging, sbt-native-packager

Sorry, I'm new to sbt and the "sbt-native-packager". What I need to do is to map whole directories to the .zip file and change the output path.

This how I've done my mapping of the directory:

```
mappings in Universal <++= (packageBin in Compile, baseDirectory ) map { (_, baseDirectory) =>
    val dir = baseDirectory / "migrations"
    (dir.***) pair relativeTo(dir.getParentFile)
}
```

The mapping works perfectly fine, but I need to have a specific folder structure in the resulting .zip file.
In this example this directory is mapped to ".../target/stage/universal/migrations" but I need it to be mapped into a folder "db" like this: ".../target/stage/db/universal/migrations"

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For mapping complete directories there are some [MappingHelpers](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formats/universal.html#mappingshelper) you can use. Your code can be simplified to

```
mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "migrations")
```

Regarding your second question, how to change the *output* folder. The question is not quite correct, as it should be: "how to change the destination path of a mapping". The universal packaging is a bit special as the target ouput looks like the resulting package.

Native packager uses `mappings` (sequence of `File -> String` tuples) that define a file and the corresponding output path in the resulting package. So if you want to change

```
# current
./target/stage/universal/migrations
# expected
./target/stage/db/universal/migrations
```

I assume you want the migrations in your zip file in a `db` folder like this

```
/        # zip root
  bin/   # start scripts
  db/    # migrations go here
  conf/  # configuration files
  lib/   # jars
```

In order to accomplish this you have to change the destination string. This would look something like this ( not tested ):

```
mappings in Universal ++= contentOf(baseDirectory.value / "migrations").map {
   case (file, dest) => file -> s"db/$dest"
}
```

cheers,
Muki

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly!
I would vote you up, but I don't have enough reputation. ^^''