# SBT Native Packager change output location of ZIP

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

This is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "DB-Services"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(UniversalPlugin,JavaServerAppPackaging)

artifactName := { (_, _, _) => "DB-Services.zip"}
Universal / mappings ++= directory(target.value)
```

Currently `sbt package` generates `DB-Services.zip` inside of `target/scala-2.12`. However I need this ZIP to be generated inside `target` folder instead. But the problem is that the `mapping` I provided above does not work and the ZIP continues to be generated inside `target/scala-2.12`.

What changes should I do in my `build.sbt` so that the ZIP is generated in `target` folder? (I cannot generate the ZIP in any other location due to limitations with our CICD)

(PS: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315241/change-output-directory-in-sbt-native-packager) answer does not work, so please do not mark this as duplicate)

Answer (score 1):

```
Universal / target := (Compile / target).value
```

Works for me. How I found this:

1. There is a useful tool in SBT to dive into settings and tasks: `inspect`
2. I ran `inspect root/Universal/packageBin` (`root/Universal/packageBin` is how we build an artifact), it returned:

   ```
   ...
   [info] Dependencies:
   [info]  Universal / packageBin / validatePackage
   [info]  Universal / packageBin / mappings
   [info]  Universal / packageName
   [info]  Universal / target
   [info]  Universal / packageBin / universalArchiveOptions
   [info]  Universal / topLevelDirectory
   ...
   ```
3. `Universal / target` looked interesting, so I ran: `inspect Universal / target` , it returned:

   ```
   ...
   [info] Description:
   [info]  Main directory for files generated by the build.
   ...
   ```

We can find that `Compile / target` returns a path to the *target* directory in a same way (or just a read docs).